# Probability distribution function of $Z=\frac{Y}{X+1}$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> I have two random variable $X,Y$ in the same space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P)}$.
>
> $X$ takes its values on $\Bbb{N}$, I denote $P(X=k):=p_k$ and $Y$ takes its values on $\Bbb{R}$? and denote $H$ his probability distribution function.

I would like to express $Z=\frac{Y}{X+1}$ in function of $H$ and $p_k$.

I know that $F_X(x)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb{N}}p_k$ but writing $F_Z(x)=P(Z\le x)=P(\frac{Y}{X+1}\le x)$ doesn't seems to 'simplify' is something about $p_k$ or $H$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no information about the joint distribution, only the marginals, of $X$ and $Y$ is given, how about the following (if $X$ and $Y$ are independent):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{Z}(z)&{}:={}&P\left(\dfrac{Y}{X{}+{}1}{}\leq{} z\right)\newline
&{}={}&P\bigg(Y{}\leq{} z\left(X{}+{}1\right)\bigg)\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}P\bigg(Y{}\leq{} z\left(x{}+{}1\right)\bigg|X{}={}x\bigg)P\left(X{}={}x\right)\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}H\bigg(z(x+1)\bigg)p_x\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: The problem is that $X,Y$ are not independent, but perhaps it's an oversight. +1 anyway.